# Toggle button text and paragraph background

Tags: javascript, html

The teacher ask us to do a JS homework.

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  button[0].onclick = changeBackground;
}

function changeBackground() {
  var allParas = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  for (var i = 0; i < allParas.length; i++) {
    allParas[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }
}
```

Here is the task detail:

Modify the HTML code to add in the button. Write the corresponding JS code (in an unobtrusive manner) to link the button to a function that highlights the paragraphs when clicked. The button should act as a “toggle”, that is, if the paragraphs are already highlighted, then clicking the button unhighlight them. If the paragraphs aren’t highlighted, then clicking the button highlights them. The button’s text should change to reflect this (see below). You can introduce additional variables to make this work.

Comment: Your picture is missing.

Comment: you need to click the homework.. there is a external link.. i dont know why

Comment: @lukazhang : Since this is your homework, am going to just give you a clue, but before that what doesnt work in your code and what does. you got to understand that, then, say your code works and highlights all text in yellow, does it go away when you click on it again? (Toggle?) 
Set a variable to know when it is yellow so that you can toggle. if yellow then white, if white then yellow and this has to happen only on click

Comment: Please check my answer below, added codepen link with your code exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `classList.toggle`:

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("p"), p => {
    p.classList.toggle("highlight");
  });
  this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML === "Highlight") ? "Unhighlight" : "Highlight";
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Cultivar brewed, coffee, spoon breve lungo spoon robust black. Barista percolator doppio, cup mug, crema, crema acerbic wings mug pumpkin spice. Lungo, aromatic, iced et, cup americano galão coffee to go.
</p>
<p>
  Cultivar brewed, coffee, spoon breve lungo spoon robust black. Barista percolator doppio, cup mug, crema, crema acerbic wings mug pumpkin spice. Lungo, aromatic, iced et, cup americano galão coffee to go.
</p>
<button id="button">Highlight</button>
```

Comment: sorry are you use the jQuery？it maybe doesn't work for me. cause the teacher ask us to use the JavaScript。。

Comment: It's plain JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

Just write another function nulling the CSS and link it to the other button.

```
function unchangeBackground(){
for (var i = 0; i < allParas.length; i++) {
   allParas[i].style.backgroundColor = " ";
} }
```

Comment: it doesn't work...  here is the task:                                            Modify the HTML code to add in the button.  Write the corresponding JS code (in an unobtrusive manner) to link the button to a function that highlights the paragraphs when clicked.  The button should act as a “toggle”, that is, if the paragraphs are already highlighted, then clicking the button unhighlight them.   If the paragraphs aren’t highlighted, then clicking the button highlights them.   The button’s text should change to reflect this (see below). You can introduce additional variables to make this work.

Comment: I apologize, to create a toggle you need to write an if statesmen that check if the style has been added. Here is a cool example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="author" content="K.">

  <title>Someone's assignment</title>

  <style>
   .yellow
   {
    background-color: yellow;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button id="toggle" type="button">Toggle highlighting</button>
  <!-- If you don't give it type="button", it works as a submit button. -->

  <p>
   Ni hao, Wo jiao K..
  </p>
  <p>
   And this is another paragraph.
  </p>

  <script>
   const toggle_button = document.getElementById("toggle");
   toggle_button.addEventListener("click", _ => {
    if(toggle_button.getAttribute("data-state") === "on")
    {
     toggle_button.setAttribute("data-state", "off");
    }
    else
    {
     toggle_button.setAttribute("data-state", "on");
    }
    const on = toggle_button.getAttribute("data-state") === "on";
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("p")).forEach(p => {
     if(on)
     {
      p.classList.add("yellow");
     }
     else
     {
      p.classList.remove("yellow");
     }
    });
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @lukazhang Could you please click the ✓?