# Highlight text button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Doing NLP using the Vader sentiment analysis tool, I'm working on a basic interface to show opinion oriented words in a text.

I got the output in HTML and I would like a button to toggle the highlight of those words in the document (noted by the `span` tag.
I tried to follow the work of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244187/toggle-button-text-and-paragraph-background) but the script doesn't work for this code.

Is there any way I could make it work ?

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("td"), td => {
    p.classList.toggle("highlight");
  });
  this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML === "Highlight") ? "Unhighlight" : "Highlight";
})
```

```css
.blue_1 { background-color:#a5c7fd; }
.blue_2 { background-color:#8ab7ff; }
.blue_3 { background-color:#609bfa; }
.blue_4 { background-color:#3682fc; }
.blue_5 { background-color:#136cfc; }

.red_1 { background-color:#fca8a8; }
.red_2 { background-color:#fa7e7e; }
.red_3 { background-color:#fa5e5e; }
.red_4 { background-color:#f83c3c; }
.red_5 { background-color:#fc1313; }
```

```html
<body>
  <table style="width:80%" border ="1">
    <tr>
      <td width="70%">
        The book is 
        <span class="blue_3">smart,</span>&nbsp;
        <span class="blue_5">handsome,</span>
        &nbsp;and&nbsp;
        <span class="blue_4">funny.</span>
        <br>
        The book is <span class="red_3">terrible <br></span>  
        The book was <span  class="blue_1">good., </span> <br> 
        Today <span class="red_4">SUX</span>!, <br> 
        Today only kinda <span class="red_4">sux!</span> <br> 
        But I'll get by, <span  class="blue_3">lol,</span> <br> 
      </td>
      <td>
        <button id="button">Highlight</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: There is some issue with `p.classList.toggle("highlight");` What is `p`, this is where I get an undefined error. If you remove the code for `forEach` it works as expected. You need to add full code. Your requirement is not clear. You say you only want to change the button text, but you are also doing something with ForEach Classlist. Better to give some clear explanation.

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code,

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("span"), p => {
    p.classList.toggle("highlight");
  });
  this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML === "Highlight") ? "Unhighlight" : "Highlight";
})
```

https://codepen.io/pgurav/pen/eYYovmN

Upvote if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Add a class for all elements you want to highlight and iterate over them. In my example I've added class `word` to all spans:

```html
<table style="width:80%" border ="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="70%">
      The book is 
      <span class="word blue_3">smart,</span>
      <span class="word blue_5">handsome,</span> and <span class="word blue_4">funny.</span><br>

      The book is <span class="word red_3">terrible <br></span>  
      The book was <span class="word blue_1">good., </span> <br> 
      Today <span class="word red_4">SUX</span>!, <br> 
      Today only kinda <span class="word red_4">sux!</span> <br> 
      But I'll get by, <span class="word blue_3">lol,</span> <br> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="button">Highlight</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

adjusted JS this way:

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('word')).forEach(
    span => span.classList.toggle("highlight")
  );
  this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML === "Highlight") ? "Unhighlight" : "Highlight";
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9gdqunfo/